# Imprimir variaveis em Ruby

Tags: ruby

Como imprimir duas variáveis em uma mesma linha(sem pular)? Já tentei usar print em vez de puts mas não funcionou.

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo do que fez? pra mim o `print` funciona http://ideone.com/PgRQpq

Comment: Vou repetir, você deve [edit] a pergunta e colocar o código que está usando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o caractere de concatenação +

```
print variavel1 + " " + variavel2
```

## ou

você pode usar dessa forma para interpretar variáveis dentro de uma string também:

```
print "Primeira variavel: #{variavel1} Segunda variavel: #{variavel2}"
```

## ou

você pode passar como se fossem 2 parâmetros

```
print variavel1,variavel2
```

Comment: Só um complemento, dê preferência à segunda maneira, ao invés da primeira é muito mais performática e é uma boa prática.

Answer (score 2):

Pra mim funcionou:

```
x = 1
y = 2
print x, y
print x
print y
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Bxr0GK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nopcuuhi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/PrintVariables.rb).

Comment: Ele funciona se a variavel for inicializada com valores definidos, mas se eu ponho um gets acontece esse problema que eu citei

Comment: bem, primeiro verifica se tem uma quebra de linha na sua string. Veja se isso resolve seu problema: print variavel1.delete('\n'),variavel2

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizei um gets.chomp e deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

O método mais recomendável é utilizar **interpolação de strings**:

```
var1 = "var1 content"
var2 = "var2 content"
puts "#{var1} #{var2}"
```

O resultado exibido será:

```
var1 content var2 content
```